# Beautiful piano song. But can't tell the title

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

I use to listen this song in the corridors of my university. And I keep thinking where does it come from. There are no lyrics, just a (hesitant) piano that interprets a song that should come from a film/series. None of my friends could identify it. But it rings a bell to me!

[Click here to listen my recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Aci9kG_u8Ny0SkVLZlEKFiYxKBCF-Rl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: apologize for the quality of the sound. i will edit when know the author

Comment: sounds like my own bad attempts to play Scott Joplin.  But hard to tell the piece from the bits in the recording. Probably one of the rags, rather than his other piano pieces, if it is by him.

Comment: @Angst I'll try to upload a better one as soon as i can

Comment: very similar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7maJOI3QMu0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good friend of mine does have a prodigious memory an after two tries he came out with a video.

I was amazed. Indeed, it is [Joe Hisaishi - Summer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEb4TG10jW8). Very appropriate title for the wonderful experience I'm having abroad this summer.

It would be wonderful if google let search songs in its engine but I think this is currently impossible right?